# Regex matching multiple occurrences per file and per line

Tags: regex, preg-replace

First post, so here goes. I'm writing a script that does intelligent search and replace on a file tree. Essentially, the script gets each file's contents into a buffer string and performs a match with a pre-defined pattern, in this case the pattern is `/^[^\r\n]*(vendor)[^\r\n]*$/im`. The pattern should find any case-insensitive forms of "vendor" and give me the entire line that was matched. I need to see the whole line in order to determine whether or not to replace the occurrence. This pattern performs well for any number of separate line occurences in a given file.

However, if there are multiple occurrences on a given line, the pattern will only match one of those occurrences, and skip the others. I'm trying to determine if I need to have a second pattern to do additional searching on the matched line, or if I can accomplish this purpose with a single pattern that does all of the above.

Just a sample of what I'm hoping to produce. An example of a single line, multi-occurrence match:

> Enthusiastically revolutionize
> web-enabled VENDOR potentialities
> vendors installed base e-tailers.

I would like to output something similar to this (again, the ouput isn't the issue here, it's whether or not I can match it all with one pattern):

> Multiple occurrences in line:  ||
> Enthusiastically revolutionize
> web-enabled VENDOR potentialities
> vendors installed base e-tailers. ||
>
> Replace? (y,n,q)  || ...abled VENDOR poten... ||
>
> Replace? (y,n,q)  || ...ties vendors insta... ||

Please let me know if I am unclear on my objective. Thanks for any help and response to this!

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: The Script is written in PHP, so the regular expressions are PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

```
/^[^\r\n]*(vendor)[^\r\n]*$/im
```

I would suggest adding the g (global) operator

```
/^[^\r\n]*(vendor)[^\r\n]*$/img
```