# Find multiple Objective-C comments per file, in certain format, with Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, comments

I'm writing a Ruby script that uses regex to find all comments of a specific format in Objective-C source code files.

The format is

```
/* <Headline_in_caps> <#>:
    <Comment body>
**/
```

I want to capture the headline in caps, the number and the body of the comment.

With the regex below I can find one comment in this format within a larger body of text.

My problem is that if there are more than one comments in the file then I end up with all the text, including code, between the first `/*` and last `**/`. **I don't want it to capture all text inclusively, but only what is within each `/*` and `**/`.**

The body of the comment can include all characters, except for `**/` and `*/` which both signify the end of a comment. Am I correct assuming that regex will find multiple-whole-regex-matches only processing text once?

`\/\*\s*([A-Z]+). (\d)\:([\w\d\D\W]+)\*{2}\//x`

Broken apart the regex does this:

`\/\*` —finds the start of a comment

`\s*` —finds whitespace

`([A-Z]+)` —captures caps word

`.<space>` —find the space in between caps word and digit

`(\d)` —capture the digit

`\:` —find the colon

`([\w\W\d\D]+)` —captures the body of a message which can include all valid characters, except `**/` or `*/`

`\*{2}\/` —finds the end of a comment

Here is a sample, everything from the first `/*` to the second `**/` is captured.:

```
/*

 HEADLINE 1:

 Comment body.

 **/

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// This text and method declaration are captured
// The regex captures from HEADLINE to the end of the comment "meddled in." inclusively.

/*
       HEADLINE 2:

       Should be captured separately and without Objective-C code meddled in. 
 **/

}
```

Here is the sample on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/4EoXXotzX0

I'm using `gsub` to process the regex on a string of the whole file, running Ruby 1.9.3. Another issue I have is that gsub gives me what Rubular ignores, is this a regression or is Rubular using a different method that gives what I want?

In this question [Regex matching multiple occurrences per file and per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234386/regex-matching-multiple-occurrences-per-file-and-per-line) about multiple occurrences the answer is to use g for the global option, that is not valid in Ruby regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:  `([\w\W\d\D]+)`
To this: `([\w\W\d\D]+?)`

This will cause the regex to be non-greedy, stopping as soon as it sees the next closing `**/`. (Updated rubular: http://rubular.com/r/Whm31AJ6Kg)

Also, note that `[\w\W\d\D]` matches absolutely any character, and can be simpler written as just `[\w\W]`. You could alternatively match the body with just `[^*\/]`, which would also avoid the above problem of matching through the close. (Updated rubular: http://rubular.com/r/2h0kGYkdVQ)

Comment: Excellent! Non-greedy is what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

- Split the whole String with `'*/'`  *(end of a comment)*
- If the split returns only one element, there is no comment in the String
- Otherwise, for each token, except the last one, use the RegExp `%r{/\*(.*)$}` *(starting at '/*' until the end of the token)* to capture the whole commented content (you may use here a more complex RegExp to capture more data in the comment)

It may not be the most beautiful solution, but it should do the job. And it's no bullet-proof, if you have in your Objective-C source code something like the line below, my solution will fail.

```
 char *myString = "a comment /*  */";
```