# Regex to extract author from /* by AUTHOR */

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex

I am developing an app based on the [programming joke blog](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com/) I have created.

In each post there is an html body that includes the image and a NSString in the following format:

```
/* by AUTHOR (SOMETIMES WITH SPACES etc) */
```

I would like to use regex to extract this author name, minus the other text. Can anyone give an example of how to do this?

EDIT:
I need the ???? line:

```
NSString *result = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: ???? 
                                                      withString:@"$1, " 
                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is always in the same format, i.e. /* TEXT */ you don't need an regex, but you could do this with a substring with range. Else if you want a regex, [here is a link to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947861/312312)

[You could also see this page](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)

Comment: /\*.*\*/ works, but how can I change it to skip the first word? I prefer regex because sometimes the text is not this format and in that case it should not return an author.